# Socket.IO namespace, call to undefined function .of()

Tags: javascript, node.js, namespaces, websocket, socket.io

I am using Node.JS 0.4.8 and Socket.IO 0.7.2.

I copied this code off their website:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000'),
    chat = socket.of('/chat');
```

however, when I execute it I get this error from FireBug.

```
socket.of is not a function
     chat = socket.of('/chat');
```

I can connect too the namespace fine with:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/chat');
```

What am i doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Fraser

Comment: Did you include the script tag for the socket.io script? And are you receiving a connection on the server side?

Comment: Yes, i can use the server fine when using `io.connect('http://localhost:8000/chat');` but not the first example

Comment: Try `chat = socket.socket.of('/chat');`

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is indeed

```
var socket = io.connect(); socket.socket.of('/namespace').on(...);
```

However, if you update to Socket.IO 0.7.7 you will have the

```
var socket = io.connect() socket.of('/namespace')
```

method available which I recently added (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/224)